# Something breaks while including a php class in ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am having a problem while including a php class with ajax.
Basically I have index.php which loads with ajax example.php. example.php includes init.php, which in turn includes a bunch of classes. I narrowed it down to users.php class, which I pasted below. I also put init.php under it just in case.

The file simply will not load with ajax. It works fine if i go directly to it.

```
<?php 
class Users{

private $db;

public function __construct($database) {
    $this->db = $database;
}   

public function update_user($first_name, $last_name, $gender, $bio, $image_location, $id){

    $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET
                            `first_name`    = ?,
                            `last_name`     = ?,
                            `gender`        = ?,
                            `bio`           = ?,
                            `image_location`= ?

                            WHERE `id`      = ? 
                            ");

    $query->bindValue(1, $first_name);
    $query->bindValue(2, $last_name);
    $query->bindValue(3, $gender);
    $query->bindValue(4, $bio);
    $query->bindValue(5, $image_location);
    $query->bindValue(6, $id);

    try{
        $query->execute();
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }   
}

public function change_password($user_id, $password) {

    global $bcrypt;

    /* Two create a Hash you do */
    $password_hash = $bcrypt->genHash($password);

    $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = ? WHERE `id` = ?");

    $query->bindValue(1, $password_hash);
    $query->bindValue(2, $user_id);             

    try{
        $query->execute();
        return true;
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}

public function recover($email, $generated_string) {

    if($generated_string == 0){
        return false;
    }else{

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ? AND `generated_string` = ?");

        $query->bindValue(1, $email);
        $query->bindValue(2, $generated_string);

        try{

            $query->execute();
            $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

            if($rows == 1){

                global $bcrypt;

                $username = $this->fetch_info('username', 'email', $email); // getting username for the use in the email.
                $user_id  = $this->fetch_info('id', 'email', $email);// We want to keep things standard and use the user's id for most of the operations. Therefore, we use id instead of email.

                $charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
                $generated_password = substr(str_shuffle($charset),0, 10);

                $this->change_password($user_id, $generated_password);

                $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `generated_string` = 0 WHERE `id` = ?");

                $query->bindValue(1, $user_id);

                $query->execute();

                mail($email, 'Your password', "Hello " . $username . ",\n\nYour your new password is: " . $generated_password . "\n\nPlease change your password once you have logged in using this password.\n\n-Example team");

            }else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public function fetch_info($what, $field, $value){

    $allowed = array('id', 'country', 'money', 'flag', 'email'); // I have only added few, but you can add more. However do not add 'password' eventhough the parameters will only be given by you and not the user, in our system.
    if (!in_array($what, $allowed, true) || !in_array($field, $allowed, true)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException;
    }else{

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT $what FROM `users` WHERE $field = ?");

        $query->bindValue(1, $value);

        try{

            $query->execute();

        } catch(PDOException $e){

            die($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $query->fetchColumn();
    }
}

public function confirm_recover($email){

    $username = $this->fetch_info('username', 'email', $email);// We want the 'id' WHERE 'email' = user's email ($email)

    $unique = uniqid('',true);
    $random = substr(str_shuffle('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'),0, 10);

    $generated_string = $unique . $random; // a random and unique string

    $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `generated_string` = ? WHERE `email` = ?");

    $query->bindValue(1, $generated_string);
    $query->bindValue(2, $email);

    try{

        $query->execute();

        mail($email, 'Recover Password', "Hello " . $username. ",\r\nPlease click the link below:\r\n\r\nhttp://www.example.com/recover.php?email=" . $email . "&generated_string=" . $generated_string . "\r\n\r\n We will generate a new password for you and send it back to your email.\r\n\r\n-- Example team");           

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function user_exists($username) {

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`= ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $username);

    try{

        $query->execute();
        $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

        if($rows == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}

public function email_exists($email) {

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email`= ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $email);

    try{

        $query->execute();
        $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

        if($rows == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}

public function register($username, $password, $email, $country, $timezone, $dst){

    global $bcrypt; // making the $bcrypt variable global so we can use here

    $date       = date( 'Y-m-d' );
    $ip         = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // getting the users IP address
    $email_code = $email_code = uniqid('code_',true); // Creating a unique string.

    $password   = $bcrypt->genHash($password);

    $query  = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `country`, `timezone`, `dst`, `ip`, `regdate`, `email_code`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");

    $query->bindValue(1, $username);
    $query->bindValue(2, $password);
    $query->bindValue(3, $email);
    $query->bindValue(4, $country);
    $query->bindValue(5, $timezone);
    $query->bindValue(6, $dst);
    $query->bindValue(7, $ip);
    $query->bindValue(8, $date);
    $query->bindValue(9, $email_code);

    try{
        $query->execute();

        mail($email, 'Please activate your account', "Hello " . $username. ",\r\nThank you for registering with us. Please visit the link below so we can activate your account:\r\n\r\nhttp://www.touringlegends.com/register.php?email=" . $email . "&email_code=" . $email_code . "\r\n\r\n-- Example team");
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }   
}

public function activate($email, $email_code) {

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ? AND `email_code` = ? AND `accountlevel` = ?");

    $query->bindValue(1, $email);
    $query->bindValue(2, $email_code);
    $query->bindValue(3, 0);

    try{

        $query->execute();
        $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

        if($rows == 1){

            $query_2 = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `accountlevel` = ? WHERE `email` = ?");

            $query_2->bindValue(1, 1);
            $query_2->bindValue(2, $email);             

            $query_2->execute();
            return true;

        }else{
            return false;
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}


public function email_confirmed($email) {

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email`= ? AND `accountlevel` >= ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $email);
    $query->bindValue(2, 1);

    try{

        $query->execute();
        $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

        if($rows == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}

public function login($email, $password) {

    global $bcrypt;  // Again make get the bcrypt variable, which is defined in init.php, which is included in login.php where this function is called

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `password`, `id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $email);

    try{

        $query->execute();
        $data               = $query->fetch();
        $stored_password    = $data['password']; // stored hashed password
        $id                 = $data['id']; // id of the user to be returned if the password is verified, below.

        if($bcrypt->verify($password, $stored_password) === true){ // using the verify method to compare the password with the stored hashed password.
            return $id; // returning the user's id.
        }else{
            return false;   
        }

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}

public function userdata($id) {

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`= ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $id);

    try{

        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetch();

    } catch(PDOException $e){

        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}

public function get_users() {

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `time` DESC");

    try{
        $query->execute();
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $query->fetchAll();

}   
}
```

init.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/connect/database.php');
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/classes/users.php');
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/classes/general.php');
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/classes/bcrypt.php');
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/classes/garage.php');

// error_reporting(0);

$users      = new Users($db);
$general    = new General();
$bcrypt     = new Bcrypt(12);

$errors = array();

if ($general->logged_in() === true)  {
$user_id    = $_SESSION['id'];
$user       = $users->userdata($user_id);
}

ob_start();
```

Here is the js loading the files (its a bit weird because its reloading jscrollpane, but working fine with html and php that dosent need external classes):

```
// Ajax
$(function () {

var api = $("#garagecontent").jScrollPane().data('jsp');

var reinitialiseScrollPane = function()
{
    api.reinitialise();
}

// attaching click handler to links
$(document).on('click', '#garagecontainer a[href]', function (e) {
    // cancel the default behaviour
    e.preventDefault();

    // get the address of the link
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    // getting the desired element for working with it later
    var $wrap = $('#garagecontent');
    $wrap
    // removing old data
    api.getContentPane()

        // load the remote page
        .load(href, reinitialiseScrollPane , function (){

        }
    );
});

});
```

I have narrowed it down to users.php because it will work when I remove it from the includes (and its functions in init.php).

Can anyone spot what is breaking my code?

Comment: what about your javascript code?

Comment: @AustinAllover Good point, added it in.

Comment: This could be a ajax cross domain issue. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Comment: @AustinAllover I checked that answer but all files im including and the including page, reside on the same domain, and physical hard drive. Unless i misread that question and the answers, it does not seem to be related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this question was using an autoloader. The page was breaking because of duplicate classes being called. My fault for having errors disabled i guess.